# how to join table group by count

Tags: sql-server

I have *query_1*:

```
select id, 
       count(case when  no01 ='B' then 1 END) +
       count(case when  no02='B' then 1 END) +
       count(case when  no03='B' then 1 END) as Count_All

From tabel_a
where date ='20150201'
group by id
```

[image]

---

and also I have *query_2*:

```
select id, COUNT (*) from tabel_b
where ids <> 'T' and idt ='C'
group by id
```

How can I join *query_1* with *query_2* via `id`?

Comment: Thank's Christian Goolhardt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using sub selects. Something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            select  id, 
                    count(case when no01 ='B' then 1 END) + count(case when no02='B' then 1 END) + count(case when no03='B' then 1 END) as Count_All
            From    tabel_a 
            where   date ='20150201' 
            group by id
        ) a INNER JOIN
        (
            select  id,     
                    COUNT (*) cnt
            from    tabel_b 
            where   ids <> 'T' 
            and     idt ='C' 
            group by id
        ) b ON  a.ID = b.ID
```

Seeing as you specified SQL Server, you could also make use of a [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Something like

```
;WITH a AS (
    select  id, 
            count(case when no01 ='B' then 1 END) + count(case when no02='B' then 1 END) + count(case when no03='B' then 1 END) as Count_All
    From    tabel_a 
    where   date ='20150201' 
    group by id
)
, b as (
    select  id,     
            COUNT (*) cnt
    from    tabel_b 
    where   ids <> 'T' 
    and     idt ='C' 
    group by id
)
SELECT  *
FROm    a INNER JOIN
        b   ON  a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Hie Adriaan Stander.. How I succes in your answer...
result like this..
id | countall | id | cnt
1  | 2           | 1 | 6

how i can result like this ?
id | countall | cnt |
1  | 2           |  6 |

Comment: oh thank's ... i can do it...
select *  from = select a.id, countall, cnt..

hehe.. thank's very much adriaan...

Comment: Change the `SELECT *` to `SELECT a.ID, a.Count_All, b.Cnt`